# Enforcing jquery callback definition on inherited views

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, web, asp.net-mvc-4

I am defining an ajax call, using jquery, on a control on my Layout page in MVC 4. I have set functionality for this call to change a session variable on the server. My problem is enforcing the callback on the views that use the layout page.

So what I need is, a way to make it so that this common callback is easily known to anyone else writing a view that uses the layout page.

--edit

An Example

In my layout I have

```
   $('#clickable').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/UrlGoesHere")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { somedata : $('#data').val() },
            success: successCallBack(data),
            error: errorCallBack(data)
        });
    });
```

In my views using this layout I would like to define successCallback or errorCallBack in a way that enforces it to those making the views.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the callback being known in views. Could you illustrate with some code example?

Comment: Edited at the requires of darin dimitrov to add example for clarification

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty hard to "enforce" developers to define method in a dynamic language like Javascript. I think the best you can do is make a well defined object for your control that is well documented on how developers are expected to use it.  If this is a control I would look at possibly encapsulating it an a JQuery UI Widget. There is a good discussion on [using widgets in the Silk Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404102.aspx) which looks at best practices for developing applications in MVC. These conventions will be understood by developers already using JQuery UI.  One of the advantages of widgets is widgets can communicate with other widgets.

The design goals are still not clear to me on why a view should handle events for a control that is defined in a layout.  Shouldn't the handling of the event be in the layout? Why would handling the event differ from view to view?  How does a developer know what type of object is returned in "data" and what to do with it?